# Merging multiple MP4 video

Tags: windows, video-editing, mp4

I am Windows user. I have about 300 .mp4 video from my XIaomi YI action camera. A duration of each file is about 2-50 seconds. I need to merge them into 1-3 file(s).

I have tried about 12 video joiner program wich I have found on Google Search. Each of them have on of the following issues: - a virus - an intallation problem - crash of performing for multiple (>80) files.

I tried to reduce the number of files in the same package up to 80, it was unsuccessful.

Do you have experience to handle such a large number of small files? Which the program could you propose?

Thank you.++

Answer (score 8):

VLC media player can convert and merge video files.

**Steps:**

1. Select File > Open Muliple Files

[image]

2. Add the required files by clicking the add button

[image]

3. From the dropdown menu below choose `convert`.
   [image]
4. Select the output format. Add a destination file name and click `start`

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this works, as of now vlc 3.0.8 the input field for "Destination file" is locked if you have multiple files selected...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this task by using [any-video-converter](http://www.anvsoft.com/any-video-converter-free.html)

[image]

The program is pretty straight forward and you don't need any special tutorial for merging videos.If you face any difficulties, take a look at [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9i9KYKJ1nGg) that explains how to merge videos.

I used this free program for many years, it is gratis, virus free and has many nice features that you cannot find in paid softwares.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for this sort of thing, *and many of the tools that you have tried may well do so behind your back*, **but** with 300+ files you are likely to hit the command line buffer size problems, *especially on windows*.

To get around this, as explained [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate), you can list all of your files in a text file in the format:

```
# This is a comment
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
#etc.
```

Then invoke ffmpeg from the command line:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

I would also suggest taking a look at [MoviePy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moviepy) - there are a few dependencies to sort out but it should let you take a list, (in the order that you specify), of files and concatenate them.

Both ffmpeg and MoviePy are:
 - Free
 - Open Source
 - Cross platform, *including windows*
 - Virus & ad-ware free

Answer (score 1):

I needed to have recorded video files from my YI CCTV installed home, but I faced all the files are fragmented and not easy to pick/merge the necessary files. I tried to find solutions on internet, but I haven't found good solution yet. I just developed a simple application can merge(concatenate) files based on the aligned time, and save that merged files to the target directory.

You can do that easily by "Yi Home Clip Merger"

http://qsok.com/display/YIHCM/YI+Home+Clip+Merger